# Как обновить powershell в windows 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7

Как обновить powershell в windows 7 до версии из windows 10?

Comment: https://www.ekzorchik.ru/2017/05/upgrading-powershell-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

RTFM
следует понимать, что нет "PowerShell из Windows 10"
Есть PowerShell определённой версии
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/skypeforbusiness/set-up-your-computer-for-windows-powershell/download-and-install-windows-powershell-5-1

Answer (score 0):

Запусти Windows PowerShell 5.1 c правами "Администратора" и выполни команду:

```
iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) } -UseMSI"
```

Данная команда загружает установочный MSI файл PowerShell 7.1.3 с GitHub и запускает установку через MSI Installer.